# Sass @Import rules and naming

Tags: css, sass

I have read many articles about importing sass files in sass but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. There seems to be many different ways of doing it.

I have tried copying a fellas setup which looks like this:

```
global
- style.scss

Components
- buttons.scss
- colors.scss
- fonts.scss
- etc.

Utils
- normalize.scss
```

So let's say this is my setup. Some people say I should name each scss file with an underscore: `_buttons.scss` while others say NOT to do it.

If I work in my `style.scss` I still need to use a `import url("components.buttons.scss")`like I've always done or am I missing something? If I'm not missing something what's the difference between this setup and a typical css setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naming your sass files with an underscore generally means that it's understood the file is being `@import`ed and therefore doesn't need to be (and won't be!) compiled as a standalone file -- though this may depend on your build system and how your sass is being compiled in the first place.

Using sass from [the command line](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass), say you have the following set of files:

```
stylesheets/
  _reset.scss
  _fonts.scss
  _header.scss
  contact-page.scss
  style.css
```

Where `style.scss` might contain:

```
@import 'reset.scss';
@import 'fonts.scss';
@import 'header.scss';
```

(Note that when importing with sass you don't need to include the underscores)

After compile, your new `stylesheets/` directory will contain only `style.css` and `contact-page.css`, and `style.scss` will include all the contents of `reset`, `fonts`, and `header`. The underscored files will not compile by themselves.

If you were to rename `_reset.scss` as `reset.scss`, it would compile to `reset.css`, but its contents would also be included in `style.css` because you're importing it as well.

So: use underscores in your file names if you don't need the file by itself and are `@import`ing it into another.

Comment: I just don't see what difference it makes. Before people used Sass they would still "import" all stylesheets in their style.css, just as they do in sass?

Comment: With native css imports, the importing happens at runtime, which is less performant. Sass imports are compiled into a single css file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we structure a sass project.

```html
<pre>stylesheets/
|
|-- modules/              # Common modules
|   |-- _all.scss         # Include to get all modules
|   |-- _utility.scss     # Module name
|   |-- _colors.scss      # Etc...
|   ...
|
|-- partials/             # Partials
|   |-- _base.sass        # imports for all mixins + global project variables
|   |-- _buttons.scss     # buttons
|   |-- _figures.scss     # figures
|   |-- _grids.scss       # grids
|   |-- _typography.scss  # typography
|   |-- _reset.scss       # reset
|   ...
|
|-- vendor/               # CSS or Sass from other projects
|   |-- _colorpicker.scss
|   |-- _jquery.ui.core.scss
|   ...
|
`-- main.scss            # primary Sass file
</pre>
```

Primary sass file will be as follows

```
// Modules and Variables
@import "partials/base";

// Partials
@import "partials/reset";
@import "partials/typography";
@import "partials/buttons";
@import "partials/figures";
@import "partials/grids";

// Third-party
@import "vendor/colorpicker";
@import "vendor/jquery.ui.core";
```

[more info](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project)

Answer (score 0):

If you add an underscore to the start of the file name, Sass won’t compile it. So, if you don’t want `colors.scss` to compile to `colors.css`, name the file `_colors.scss` instead. Files named this way are called partials in Sass terminology.

More about it you can read [here](https://kolosek.com/sass-import/).