# How to name a Sass file containing only @import statements

Tags: css, sass

How should one name a Sass file that has the sole purpose of importing other Sass files?

Are there any rules or general "industry standards" that apply to this?

Let's suppose we have the following file structure:

```
sass/
|-- global/
|   `-- file.sass
`-- vendor/
    `-- bootstrap/
        |-- variables.sass
        `-- mixins.sass
```

and `file.sass` under `global/` contains only

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/variables";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/mixins";
```

How should `file.sass` be named?

Is it `bootstrap.sass` or `bootstrap-loader.sass`? Or something else?

I couldn't find any relevant post or documentation that addresses this matter except this Stack Overflow thread:
[Sass @Import rules and naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360152/sass-import-rules-and-naming) which is somewhat similar but it doesn't cover my question.

Please support your answer with arguments / examples if possible.

Comment: The sole purpose of that name would be to tell future developers of your project what it contains without having to open it. So you could name it `global`, `imports`, `general` or `all`. But, in the end, it's opinion based. The effort you put into writing this question far exceeds the benefit you'd get from naming that file according to other developer's preferences which, by the way, is quite close to `null`. The conditions are *"it has to make sense"* and the naming convention "*should be consistent across the entire project*".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AndreiGheorghiu, but you are missing a couple of things. First of all, I don't want to do "effort" savings, I am just trying to improve myself and my coding best practices, just as other users around may want. Secondly, I don't agree with any of the examples you gave (`global`, `imports`, `general`, `all`). Mine is a specific case where I'm importing only some of the files from a vendor / library / module. Though I agree with you that the name "_has to make sense_" to future developers & "_should be consistent across the entire project_".

Comment: While consistent and understandable naming conventions greatly reduce development time in the long run, especially in large-scale applications, there's no way to technically determine one correct way of naming that file. Which means any answer will be *opinionated*. And that's demonstrated by exactly the fact you dismissed all of my otherwise decent suggestions, which 3 other developers seem to have agreed with. Which makes your question **off-topic** on [so]. Additionally, my comment was not an answer, specifically because, according to SO guidelines, your question should not be answered.

Answer (score 3):

The primary CSS/Sass file is usually called main.scss/main.css or style.scss/style.css.

Citing [thesassyway.com](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project) here's how the structure looks like:

```
stylesheets/
|
|-- modules/              # Common modules
|   |-- _all.scss         # Include to get all modules
|   |-- _utility.scss     # Module name
|   |-- _colors.scss      # Etc...
|   ...
|
|-- partials/             # Partials
|   |-- _base.sass        # imports for all mixins + global project variables
|   |-- _buttons.scss     # buttons
|   |-- _figures.scss     # figures
|   |-- _grids.scss       # grids
|   |-- _typography.scss  # typography
|   |-- _reset.scss       # reset
|   ...
|
|-- vendor/               # CSS or Sass from other projects
|   |-- _colorpicker.scss
|   |-- _jquery.ui.core.scss
|   ...
|
`-- main.scss            # primary Sass file
```

In an enterprise-level project where multiple sub-projects are bundled you can name and divide your primary file into different files and name them after each project.

```
stylesheets/
|
|-- admin/           # Admin sub-project
|   |-- modules/
|   |-- partials/
|   `-- _base.scss
|
|-- account/         # Account sub-project
|   |-- modules/
|   |-- partials/
|   `-- _base.scss
|
|-- site/            # Site sub-project
|   |-- modules/
|   |-- partials/
|   `-- _base.scss
|
|-- vendor/          # CSS or Sass from other projects
|   |-- _colorpicker-1.1.scss
|   |-- _jquery.ui.core-1.9.1.scss
|   ...
|
|-- admin.scss       # Primary stylesheets for each project
|-- account.scss
`-- site.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

It would all depend on how you intend to compile your scss in the project, and how the workflow of the project works.

Typically you would use "Partial" scss files for anything that you don't want compiling separately.

> A partial is simply a Sass file named with a leading underscore. You might name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are used with the @import directive. Source: https://sass-lang.com/guide

A basic typical workflow inside a project may look like the follow.. (Depending on how much scope the project has):

```
Src (Folder)
-- JS (Folder)
--Scss (Folder)
   -- Components (Folder)
       -- _button.scss
       -- _animation.scss
   -- Pages Folder
       -- cms (Folder)
          -- _about.scss
          -- _contact.scss
-- _components.scss
-- _source.scss
-- default.scss
```

Inside _source.scss:
Import all cms page partials/other..

```
@import
'pages/cms/button',
'pages/cms/animation';
```

Note: You do not need to use an underscore before the file names in this import.

Inside _components.scss:
Import all partial component files.. (Same as source)

You would then import these into a file which you want to be compiled.. (No underscore file name):

default.scss:

```
@import
'components';


@import
'source';
```

I hope this answers your question.